# Make GTK or KDE text fields be Vi-like?

Tags: vim, kde, vi, gtk, vi-mode

Is there a way to make all GTK or KDE text fields Vi-like, akin to what `set -o vi` in `~/.bashrc` does with the Bash shell?

Comment: so that they have command vs editing modes, ala `set -o vi` in a shell?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes. I've added that clarification to my question.